# Difference between reports generated in two different servers

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I stumbled in a weird problem in which the same report generated in one server is different from the one generated on another server.

The package deployed (WAR file) is the same, I checked event the MD5 of it. The same data is being used to generate the report, so no difference from the application itself.

I took a look into the Java version and the one that is generating the report as expected is using Oracle JVM 1.7 and the one generating the weird formated report is using OpenJDK.

I suppose this should be the problem right? In this case what else could I check to maybe find the problem?

Things I already have checked are:

- war file deployed to both servers;
- fonts installed on both servers are the same;
- version of both servers (right one is being run on a apache-tomcat-7.0.28 and the weird one apache-tomcat-7.0.29);
- properties and version of libraries;

**ADD**

Within the report I have a few fields that are justified, and these are stretched and line break is positioned in a quite strange position.

[image]

For example the blue area should present 2 lines, but it presents 3, the second is the word with a big letter spacing and a 3rd one with just one word that should be on the second line. And the green area is presenting 2 lines which is fine but the last line it is justifying the word to the entire line increasing the space between the letters.

Comment: What is different about the two reports? The layout? The data?

Comment: @JavaMentor May be you have: 1) different version of *JasperReports library* or other related with *JR* libraries (*POI*, for example) 2) different properties file: *default.jasperreports.properties* or *jasperreports_extension.properties*

Comment: just commented the question with both requested informations

Comment: @JavaMentor And what is output format?

Comment: @AlexK I'm generating PDF with the report

Comment: @JavaMentor Did you check\compare the fonts used in *PDF* files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recheck all the configuration and components and here is the result:

- upgrading locally tomcat to 7.0.29 didn't solved the problem;
- fonts configured are exactly the same;
- font visually resulted in both PDF files are the same;
- no log output from JR that could indicate something is missing / wrong;
- war file (deployment package) is the same (lib are the same);
- server configuration are the same;

What was missing is to change the JVM, and indeed changing JVM from OpenJDK 1.6.0-b09 to Oracle JVM 1.7.0_25-b15 solved the problem.